# MariaDB4j dumping database results in deadlock when using .waitFor()

Tags: java, database, spring-boot, maven, mariadb4j

When I imported a .sql file into the running database, then modify the data within and then want to dump the database, it has a problem.
I can run `db.dumpSQL(file, "smdb", "root", "1234").start().waitForExitMaxMs(10000);` it waits 10 seconds and then starts the process. Using `.waitForExit()` it does never start and it deadlocked.

My OS is windows and my application will be run on windows and linux later.
My application build onto spring (if it's important)

My configuration looks like:

```java
package sv_fix.config;

import ch.vorburger.exec.ManagedProcessException;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DB;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.DBConfigurationBuilder;
import ch.vorburger.mariadb4j.springframework.MariaDB4jSpringService;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.Properties;

import javax.sql.DataSource;

import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

import org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.support.PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer;
import org.springframework.util.StreamUtils;

@Slf4j
@Configuration
public class DatabaseConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService() {
        MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService = new MariaDB4jSpringService();
        configureMariaDB4jSpringService(mariaDB4jSpringService);

        return mariaDB4jSpringService;
    }

    @Bean
    DataSource dataSource(MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService,
                          @Value("${spring.datasource.username}") String datasourceUsername,
                          @Value("${spring.datasource.password}") String datasourcePassword) {
        //Create our database with default root user and no password
        DBConfigurationBuilder config = mariaDB4jSpringService.getConfiguration();

        return DataSourceBuilder
                .create()
                .username(datasourceUsername)
                .password(datasourcePassword)
                .url(config.getURL("SMDB"))
                .driverClassName("org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver") // Correct driver class name
                .build();
    }

    protected void configureMariaDB4jSpringService(
            @SuppressWarnings("unused") MariaDB4jSpringService mariaDB4jSpringService) {
        DBConfigurationBuilder config = mariaDB4jSpringService.getConfiguration();
        config.setPort(3306); // Set the port to 3306
        mariaDB4jSpringService.start();
        DB db = mariaDB4jSpringService.getDB();
        File currentDirectory = new File(".");

        // Get the list of all files in the current directory
        File[] filesList = currentDirectory.listFiles();
        
        try {
            for (File file : filesList) {
                if (file.getName().equals("backup.sql")) {
                    db.source(FileUtils.openInputStream(file)); // Load your .sql file
                }
            }
        } catch (ManagedProcessException e) {
            log.error("Failed constructing Database", e);
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Bean
    PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer propertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer() {
        PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer ppc = new PropertySourcesPlaceholderConfigurer();
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        ppc.setProperties(properties);
        return ppc;
    }
}
```

And my Spring-application like:

```java
package sv_fix;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import sv_fix.services.Fixer;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SvFixApplication {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SvFixApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public CommandLineRunner run(Fixer fixer){
        return (args -> fixer.fix());
    }
}
```

Is there a problem within my usage, or how would I dump the sql file, wait for end of the execution of the dumping and then continue?

I did try to look at the source code vorburger has provided, but I can't see anything out of the ordanary. I also opened a github issue, but no answer.

I then tried using Threads in various places to maybe have the blocking part on another thread, but sadly to no avail.